# Are conditional subqueries optimized out, if the condition is false?

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, oracle, subquery

I have a table foo and a table bar, where each foo might have a bar (and a bar might belong to multiple foos).

Now I need to select all foos with a bar. My sql looks like this

```
SELECT * 
  FROM foo f 
 WHERE [...] 
   AND ($param IS NULL OR (SELECT ((COUNT(*))>0) 
                             FROM bar b 
                            WHERE f.bar = b.id))
```

with $param being replaced at runtime.

The question is: Will the subquery be executed even if param is null, or will the dbms optimize the subquery out?

We are using mysql, mssql and oracle. Is there a difference between these regarding the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. If you are passing that query to the DBMS each time, then the compiler should realize that it does not need to call the subquery. If it is a static procedure, then it depends on how the compiler stores the execution plan. If it stores the execution plan the first time the procedure is called and the first time it is called $param is not null, then it might actually call the subquery each time the procedure is run.

On a different note, you should consider Exists instead of Count(*) for this type of check

```
Select ..
From foo f
Where ....
    And ( $param Is Null
            Or Exists   (
                        Select 1
                        From bar b
                        Where b.id = f.bar
                        ))
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case I recommend doing the optimization yourself in the application code, rather than relying on the optimizer from 3 different RDBMSs to consistently handle this the way you want.

If $param is null, just select from foo table.
If not, join to the bar table.

pseudo-code:

```
if ($param is null)
  SELECT * 
  FROM foo f 
  WHERE [...] 
else
  SELECT distinct f.* 
  FROM foo f 
  inner join bar b on f.bar = b.id
  WHERE [...] 
end if
```

Comment: I don't recommend this approach, for the sake that you'll be encapsulating three (or more) databases syntax which will diverge.  IE: MySQL supports LIMIT, which neither SQL Server or Oracle do -- SQL Server uses TOP while Oracle uses ROWNUM.  Either use a database abstraction tech like Hibernate/etc so you aren't burdened with coding the various SQL yourself, or leverage each databases' stored procedure/function to code & tune queries for each.

Comment: To clarify, my `if...else...end if` pseudo-code is meant to be in the application layer, not in SQL. I'm not recommending adding complexity to the SQL, actually I think the SQL should be simplified. The main point I was making is that if you have a simple conditional like `$param is null` you're probably better off moving that out of the SQL and into the application layer. This should work regardless of whether OP is using Hibernate,etc or writing straight SQL.

Comment: Yes, we are using a db abstraction layer, home-brewed, with so called named queries, which are written in xml files and accessed from our code. The parameters are passed from the code, and the sql is generated by the abstraction layer. Therefore the easiest way for now is to use the kind of ($param is null || $param == ...) as I have done in the sample. The only drawback so far has been that the resulting sql is cluttered with null is null... that hinders debugging a bit, but has never been a performance problem so far -- until now, where I need a conditional join.